# Convert multiple types of dates

Tags: python, date, datetime, format

I'm working with data that comes from different places and need to convert dates into the same format. Below are few examples of what I have:

```
Thu Dec 03 07:27:23 GMT 2015
3-Dec-15
2015-12-04T06:58:54Z
23-Sep-2015 07:03:37 UTC
```

The desired output format should be the same for all dates, like this:

```
12/03/2007
12/03/2015
12/04/2015
09/23/2015
```

Any suggestions how to achieve that with Python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks!!

Comment: Definitely will! It won't let me for 5 min after the question was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5) library provides date format detection with the [`parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) function :

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(text).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: External libraries are often more simple :) especially `dateutil` which is awesome.  Thanks for the correction, I edited the post.